# How to determine various Java 8 Heap Memory Names?

Tags: java, java-8, heap-memory

I want to determine programmatically Java Heap Memory Name. When I ran the below code it is giving two different names for java heap memory even when same java is installed on two different machines.

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryPoolMXBean;
import java.lang.management.MemoryType;

public class MemTest {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        for (MemoryPoolMXBean mpBean : ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) {
            System.out.println(mpBean.getType());
            System.out.println(mpBean.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Output from Machine 1

```
support@vrni-platform:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
support@vrni-platform:~$ vi MemTest.java
support@vrni-platform:~$ javac MemTest.java
support@vrni-platform:~$ java MemTest
Non-heap memory
Code Cache
Non-heap memory
Metaspace
Non-heap memory
Compressed Class Space
Heap memory
PS Eden Space
Heap memory
PS Survivor Space
Heap memory
PS Old Gen
```

Output of java settings

```
java -XshowSettings:vm -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:InitialHeapSize=32773376 -XX:MaxHeapSize=524374016 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 485.31M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: client
    Using VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

Output from Machine 2

```
support@vrni-platform:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~/logs/tsdb-server$ vim MemTest.java
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~/logs/tsdb-server$ javac MemTest.java
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~/logs/tsdb-server$ java MemTest
Non-heap memory
Code Cache
Non-heap memory
Metaspace
Non-heap memory
Compressed Class Space
Heap memory
Eden Space
Heap memory
Survivor Space
Heap memory
Tenured Gen
```

Output of java settings

```
java -XshowSettings:vm -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:InitialHeapSize=262920896 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4206734336 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 3.48G
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

Can some one let me know why this is giving two different names for Heap Memory when environment is same (Ubuntu 14.04, Java Version is same)? What are all possible names for `Heap Memory` ?

Comment: What is the output of `java -XshowSettings:vm -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version` on both machines? Are there any differences between the machines (eg amount of memory, number of CPU cores, etc)?

Comment: They are different. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heap memory regions are a feature of the garbage collector used.

The difference between the machines is caused by the fact that machine 1 is classified as a client machine, while machine 2 is classified as a server machine. The reason is the amount of available memory. The classification difference causes a different garbage collector to be selected (specifically the serial collector for machine 1 and the parallel collector for machine 2), which in turn causes the difference in heap memory regions.

See also the [Java Platform, Standard Edition HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html), specifically the section [Garbage Collector, Heap, and Runtime Compiler Default Selections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html#sthref5).